# Problem with Logstash configuration file using Mongodb input plugin

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, configuration-files

I am getting this error while running the conf file

**[2019-10-24T16:17:09,572][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyNil cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyFixnum, :backtrace=>["org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.MathLinker.fixnum_op_equal(MathLinker.java:237)", "java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)", "org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.MathLinker.fixnumOperator(MathLinker.java:171)", "D_3a_.Elastic.logstash_minus_7_dot_4_dot_0.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.mongo_minus_2_dot_10_dot_2.lib.mongo.server_selector.selectable.RUBY$method$initialize$0(D:/Elastic/logstash-7.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/mongo-2.10.2/lib/mongo/server_selector/selectable.rb:46)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:91)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:90)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:915)",** ... and a lot of other rows

This is my config file

```
input{
    mongodb{
        uri=>"mongodb://localhost:27017/Tesi"
        placeholder_db_dir=>"D:\Elastic\logstash-7.4.0"
        placeholder_db_name=>"commenti_sqlite.db"
        collection=>"Commenti_youtube"
        batch_size=>5000
    }
}
filter{
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts=>["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

what's wrong with my configuration file?

Are there other ways to pass MongoDb data to logstash?

Comment: I have for a fresh installation, for a different plugin the same error, cannot cast to RubyFixnum. And while looking for the answer I found [issue 11196](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11196). Apparently this is fixed in JRuby 9.2.9. I have a second logstash server which was updated, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks, i solved by downgrading logstash to the version 7.3.2